# shmget returns different id for same key

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

Hello I made small 'client-server' file transfer program in Linux. But something strange is happening. If I launch first client and then server everything work fine. shmget() giving same id for provided key. Unfortunately if I launch first server and then client I am getting different id in client and I cannot copy data.
I am using IPC_CREAT flag so it should join to shared memory.

**client**

```
id=shmget(138134,1,0777|IPC_CREAT);
```

**server**

```
id=shmget(138134,1,0777|IPC_CREAT);
```

[image: Shared Memory Segments screen]

**client**
[image]

**server**
[image]

**Basic info**
So basically there is semaphore with 3 elements. Server | sem0 | sharedmemory | sem1 | client. Sem2 is used when server and client will find EOF. And I copy data character after character. Client and server are both have the same functions. There are basic semaphore and shared memory funcion to creating, deleting etc. The only difference is in main. Unfortunately code is in Polish language but maybe it will help a little.

**server main**

```
utworz_nowy_semafor();//semaphore creating
    upd(); //shared memory creating
    upa(); //shared memory attaching
    odlaczenie1=shmctl(pamiec,IPC_RMID,0); //marking shared memory to delete(waiting for detach)
    FILE* we = fopen("zrodlo", "r");
    if(we == NULL)
    {
        printf("Blad otwierania pliku wejsciowego");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Otworzony plik wejsciowy\n");
    }
    int c;
    semafor_v(0); // opening the gate
    while((c = fgetc(we)) != EOF)
    {
        semafor_p(0); // closing the gate
        wstaw(c);
        semafor_v(1);
    }
 semafor_p(0);
    wstaw(c);
    semafor_v(1);
    fclose(we);
    printf("Zamknalem pilk zrodlowy! Czekam na sygnal od konsumenta aby zakonczyc dzialanie\$
    semafor_p(2);
    printf("Konsument skonczył kopiowanie. Zamykam program!\n");
    odlaczenie2=shmdt(adres);
    if (odlaczenie1==-1 || odlaczenie2==-1)
      {
        printf("Problemy z odlaczeniem pamieci dzielonej.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    else printf("Pamiec dzielona zostala odlaczona.\n");
    //odlacz_pamiec();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

**client main**

```
utworz_nowy_semafor();
    upd();
    upa();
    FILE* wy; wy = fopen("wynik", "w");
    if(wy == NULL)
    {
        printf("Blad tworzenia pliku");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Plik wynikowy utworzony!\n");
    }
    while(1 != 0)
    {
         semafor_p(1);
         char c = wez();
         if(c == EOF)
         {
              printf("Nastąpił koniec pliku. Wykonuję przerwanie petli\n");
              fclose(wy);
              break;
         }
         fputc(c, wy);
         printf("Konsument odebral znak: %c\n",c);
         semafor_v(0);
    }
    semafor_v(2);
    usun_semafor();
    odlaczenie1=shmctl(pamiec,IPC_RMID,0);
    odlaczenie2=shmdt(adres);
    if (odlaczenie1==-1 || odlaczenie2==-1)
     {
        printf("Problemy z odlaczeniem pamieci dzielonej.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
        else printf("Pamiec dzielona zostala odlaczona.\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Comment: Can you give us more context? Are you sure that the third display segment is not an old test? What is the return of `shmget`? What about a [MCVE]?

Comment: @Mathieu the third display isnt and old test, now I edited post and provided more details

Comment: `shmget` is not called in your example code.

Comment: shmget is called in upa() function

Comment: Fixed: I cannot mark semaphore to detach until client will join to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: I cannot mark semaphore to detach until client will join to it